# Web Audio API gaindrops

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I've run into a problem using the Web Audio API.

[image: Gain drop example]

When I connect a gain-node to the chain and change the gain on it, say -6.0dB, it will immediately decrease the gain much more than 6.0dB and then slowly bring the volume back up. Similar to having a slow-release compressor somewhere in the chain. I've experienced the same thing with the BiquadFilterNode
and its more noticeable for bass-heavy content.

I'm using the following code to setup the gain-node:

```
var gainNode = context.createGain();
source.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(context.destination);
```

and this to change the gain:

```
gainNode.gain.value = -6.0;
```

It's not just a dB or two of extra drop, at times the audio is completely silent on a 6dB drop and fades back in over 2-3 seconds.

I don't see this problem on other sites using Web Audio API so I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious here but I can't figure it out. And yes, I'm new to this API.

Any ideas would be very helpful! It there an auto-gain or something by default that I need to disable?

Answer (score 0):

The gain value is absolute so you don't decrease the value with -6 you set it to -6.

As the documentation says one shouldn't do that. Try to stay between 0 and 20. 0 is nothing and 20 is very loud. 1 is 100%.

You can do negative values though because you can use the gain node to manipulate the frequency from an oscilliator to a filter for example. See on my website gtube.de => PUBLISH to get some impressions of how the nodes run in each other on an FM modulation.

But to handle pure volume please stay between 0 and whatever, but not negative.